# ¿Como django recibe los datos enviados por el método POST?

Tags: django, django-forms

Tengo una vista basada en clase, un `CreateView` y es la siguiente:

```
@method_decorator(staff_member_required, name = 'dispatch')
class PageCreate(CreateView):
    model = Page
    form_class = PageForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('pages:pages')
```

Y este seria el `template` donde muestro el formulario de `PageCreate`:

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}Crear página{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
{% include 'pages/includes/pages_menu.html'%}
  <main role="main">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row mt-3 mb-5">
  <div class="col-md-9 mx-auto">
    <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <div class="text-center">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Crear página" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
{% endblock %}
```

Bueno mi duda es ¿Como es que `django` recibe los datos enviados por el método POST? Lo recibe en la vista(`PageCreate`)?.

Tengo la duda también de que en ningún momento se indica en el atributo `action` de la etiqueta `form` a donde se enviaran los datos, ¿Entonces a donde se envían los datos exactamente? y nuevamente ¿Acaso recibe los datos la vista(`PageCreate`)?

Se los agradecería mucho que me explicaran sobre este tema para así poder resolver mi dudas...

**De antemano muchas gracias por sus respuestas!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando no defines `action` por defecto HTML hace que se envíen a la misma url donde está el formulario. Por lo que si en tu archivo de urls definiste que el formulario se va a renderizar cuando consulten la url */hola* entonces, el formulario enviará la petición a esa dirección pero con un POST. Esto puedes verificarlo desde el inspector del navegador que uses en la pestaña de `Network`.

Según dice [esta](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.1/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/#post) página (te recomiendo que la guardes, ya que si trabajas con *Class Based Views* te será muy útil). Te responderé las preguntas:

> ¿Cómo es que Django recibe los datos enviados por el método **POST**?

Responder tu pregunta tal cual, es algo complicado, si quisieras saber la forma exacta en cuando Django recibe los parámetros por POST, deberás ver el código del objeto `RequestDict` (No recuerdo el nombre exacto) y a partir de ahí, ver como lee la petición en raw y como hace el parse. De todas formas ese proceso es algo repetitivo y no es muy interesante de saber, solo debemos confiar que Django tiene los datos si se los hemos envíado. Ahora, la forma de recuperarlos siempre será la misma en Django, para ello puedes entrar a tu método `post` dentro de la clase, te recomiendo hacerlo así:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
  print(request.POST)  # de esta forma estás viendo los datos que se envían en el formulario de HTML
  return super(self.__class__, request, *args, **kwargs)
```

> ¿Lo recibe en la vista *PageCreate*?

Para responder esta pregunta, necesitaría ver tu archivo de `urls.py` y efectivamente saber que todo está "ruteado" para que así lo pueda recibir, pero depende de eso. Django no hará nada que no le pidas que haga, así que lo más probable es que si definiste la url del formulario a `GET /formulario` entonces el envíe el formulario a `POST /formulario` y será la misma clase *PageCreate*, solo que atendiendo diferentes métodos. Si quieres comprobar, te bastaría con verificar los logs y añadir este código:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
  print("Esto es un GET")
  return super(self.__class__, request, *args, **kwargs)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
  print("Esto es un POST")
  return super(self.__class__, request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Espero que esto pueda ayudarte a resolver tus preguntas, pero cualquier pregunta que tengas no dudes en comentar y con gusto te ayudaré a responderlas

Comment: Gracias por responder, tengo una pregunta. añadí el método `post` a la vista basada en clase e imprimí el `request.POST` y me imprimió el `queryset` con los datos con el cual cree la `page`, esto significa que la vista es el que recibe los datos por el método POST no?

Comment: No entiendo a qué te refieres exactamente cuando mencionas el `queryset`. Ten en cuenta que un QuerySet en Django es lo que te retorna luego de una llamada a una base de datos, por ejemplo, hacer `Page.objects.all()` debe retornar un queryset. El punto que quiero que identifiques es que seguramente debes tener muchas vistas y urls en tu app, pero hizo el print de lo que le pusiste, eso quiere decir que de todas las vistas que tienes, solo está entrando a la que quieres que entre, creo que eso responde a tu pregunta

Comment: Me dio esta `queryset`: <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['YOlSZzuwHfXymlRuRf4xpgAxh4zliqbpWAAMbVClJ1tMG4wkMpgbLJtgD4186YcT'], 'title': ['Titulooo'], 'content': ['<p>dwadwdadwwdawdadawd</p>\r\n'], 'order': ['3']}> Entonces que esta pasando exactamente?

Comment: Vale, ese es el QueryDict (distinto a QuerySet) que es el diccionario que Django en su proceso que te comenté arriba genera a partir de los datos del form. Si verificas, esos son los datos que envíaste desde el formulario. Si verificas en Network dentro del inspector del navegador, verás que esos son los datos que envíaste desde el formulario

Comment: Ahhh ok, perdón por mi falta de conocimiento, entonces la vista es la que recibe los datos por el método POST no?

Comment: Si lo quieres ver así, también es correcto, ya lo acabas de comprobar

Comment: Y como lo ves tu? quiero saber tu opinión :-)

Comment: Lo que sucede es que es cuestión de perspectiva, lo que yo quiero llevarte a que veas es que si lo que está en el QueryDict cuando haces el `print(request.POST)` son los mismos datos que enviaste en el formulario, entonces efectivamente lo está recibiendo tu vista, si no fuese así, tuvieses que ir a otra vista a hacer el `print` y si quieres inténtalo, ve a otra vista y pones un `print` y mira si se ejecuta, pero al final todo depende de tus urls

Comment: Pues si cuando hago el `print(request.POST)` son los mismos datos que escribí en el formulario.

Comment: Estupendo! eso significa que entonces tu vista si está recibiendo los datos

Comment: Ok muchas gracias! por tomarte el tiempo de resolver mis dudas, por cierto que es una `QueryDict`?